# Impact of Docker Containers in Kubernetes Master Node

Tags: docker, kubernetes, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-chaincode

I am currently working with a Hyperledger Fabric v1.4 deployment over k8s. The chaincode containers that are generated are basically create by the container running within the peer pods and k8s as such has no knowledge and control of the chaincode containers. In such a scenario where there is a Docker container running along with k8s and k8s has no knowledge of a particular docker container, is it possible for the Docker container to in some way gain access to the k8s master API and gain access to the whole k8s cluster consequently?

My intention with asking this question is to figure out if there is a way to use an container external to any pods in k8s, to cause any undesirable impact to the k8s cluster by gaining unauthorized access to k8s. The chaincode container that I talked about, is created using a trusted template image and the only possible malicious component in the container is a single golang, java or nodejs script that is provided by the user. So my real question here is, "Is it possible using these user scripts gain unauthorized access to the k8s cluster?" And I am primarily focusing on a manager k8s service like Azure Kubernetes Service.

Answer (score 0):

Your question totally changed the meaning so I'll try to rewrite the answer.

You have to remember that the `pod` you are running the code on by default is limited to just the `namespace` it's running on. If you didn't gave it any higher privileges. Also the code is not running as root.

You can read about [Pod Security Policies](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/policy/pod-security-policy/) and [Configure a Security Context for a Pod or Container](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/security-context/).

TLDR.
As long as you don't give it any special privileges or rights it should be fairly save for your cluster.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the details answer @Crou!! I will definitely look into all these resources. Just a follow up though. My intention with this question was to figure out if there was a way to use an external container to cause any undesirable impact to the k8s cluster by gaining unauthorized access. The chaincode container that I talked about, is created by trusted template and the only malicious component is one single golang, java or nodejs script that is provided by the user. So my real question here is, "Is it possible using these user scripts go gain unauthorized access to the k8s cluster?"

Comment: @HardikGourisaria, I've rewrote the answer. Hope this provides more details.

Comment: I will take a look @Crou. Thanks a lot for taking the time to answer my question. And sincere apologies for any sort of misunderstanding.

Comment: This is not really really the case. Fabric 1.4 requires access to the actual Docker daemon via running your pod in privileged mode, which exists outside of namespaces. Aside from taking general security precautions (properly configuring firewalls, validating chaincode), this is the extent of what you can do to protect yourself.

Comment: Fabric 2.0 introduced external builders, which allow you to totally separate the chaincode management from the peer, and thus break free from the docker daemon requirement. You can read about the new model here: https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.0/cc_launcher.html